# How render more items form top and from bottom?

Tags: flutter, listview, caching, builder, flutter-listview

I need to render items in list form top and bottom without using listView because it will fill phone memory.Is anyway to do it?

I used the cacheExtent property but it only worked once, I want to use the cache in the scrolling process as well.

Comment: Use `ListView.builder`, that automatically unloads and loads items as needed to prevent high memory usage scenario.

Comment: Yes I know but listView.builder render only visible items, I need render a little more from top and bottom that is not visible.